# Static webdriver is null in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am starting with selenium and also read about the Page Object Model. I tried to implement sample code and now i have 2 questions:

1. How do i start another test case after the login is tested?
2. I implemented a static WebDriver to access it from everywhere. Why is it null in case 2?

My WebDriver-Class:

```
public class BrowserFactory {


public static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public static WebDriver startBrowser(String browserName, String url) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\selenium-driver\\geckodriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\selenium-driver\\chromedriver.exe");

    if (browserName.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("No Browser Parameter given, use default Browser Firefox");
        browserName = "Firefox";
    }

    if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")){
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }else {
        System.out.println("Browser not defined!");
        throw new Exception("Browser not defined!");
    }

    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(url);

    return driver;
}

@AfterClass
public void teardown () {
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

LoginTest-Class (working):

```
public class LoginPageTest {


@Test
public void checkValidUser() throws Exception {

    BrowserFactory.driver = BrowserFactory.startBrowser("Chrome","http://localhost:8080/cleo");
    LoginPage loginPage=new LoginPage(BrowserFactory.driver);
    KundenverwaltungPage kundenVerwaltungPage = new KundenverwaltungPage(BrowserFactory.driver);

    assertTrue(loginPage.isInitialized());

    loginPage.loginCleo("makler1", "12345a");

    assertTrue(kundenVerwaltungPage.isInitialized());

}
}
```

Test-Case 2:

```
public class SecondCasePageTest {

@Test
public void processSelectedKunden() throws Exception {

    System.out.println(BrowserFactory.driver);

    SecondCasePage scPage = new SecondCasePage(BrowserFactory.driver);

    assertTrue(scPage.isInitialized());

    scPage.selectCostumer(0);


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your second test case you are calling `System.out.println(BrowserFactory.driver);` without assigning any value to the `BrowserFactory.driver`

Just like the first test case you need to `BrowserFactory.driver = BrowserFactory.startBrowser("Chrome","http://localhost:8080/cleo");` and then do `System.out.println(BrowserFactory.driver);`

At this point of time the driver itself is not `null`

I'd say to modify this design. Since you are using `nUnit` framework you can just extend `BrowserFactory` class in your test cases. That way the `startBrowser` method is automatically executed due to `beforeClass` annotation. So that you don't really have to worry about the driver being null.

It would look like

```
public class LoginPageTest extends BrowserFactory {

...

}
```

Also it is not a good idea to set the `driver` as a `static` as you might run into multi threading issue when you start running test cases in parallel using `testNG`

As far as question #1 is concerned you can create a `testng.xml` with both your test cases and then run the `testng.xml`. This will help you run both the test cases. But pls remember that the order of the test cases execution is not guaranteed. In this case you should start using `@dependsOnGroups` annotation or you can also use `preserve-order="true"` in your `testng.xml`

Comment: I will change my design. But the second test case can only be executed if the login is done. So i don't want to set up the driver every time. How do i design this in a convinient way?

Comment: Move the second test into your first test with another `@test` on your `processSelectedKunden` method after the `loginTest`. Is there a reason why they have to be in two separate classes?

Comment: I thought it would be a more clear way if tests referring to a specific page are in seperate classes. It is also mentioned in many tutorials.

Comment: Well, Yes. But why don't you extract your `login` method and `processSelectedKunden` method into your page object classes and then do `LoginPage.loginTest()` and `KundenPage.processSelectedKunden()`. This way you are abstracting the implementation and also easier to maintain if needed.
But if you don't want to do this then testNG allows you to `setAttribute` in `ITestContext`. Then use `getTestContext().getAttribute` method to retrieve your driver. I don't recommend doing that as it's a workaround

Comment: Best practice is to have each test be independent. You should create a new driver instance at the start of each test. Many of your test cases will have login be the first thing that is done... that's just the nature of testing a site that requires login. You don't want to have one test log in and then have another test use that login to proceed. You are going to end up relying on a single browser for all your tests which will get messy and you will end up in a bad state because of another test which will cause many other tests to fail.

Comment: I tried to extend from the BrowserFactory class but then i get the message `Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a @BeforeClass annotated startBrowser.` However i need the parameters to select a browser. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: You cannot have `String browserName, String url` as args for the `startBrowser` method as `TestNG` `beforeClass` is does not know what to inject to your `browserName` and `url`. Use `testng.xml` to pass parameters like this `<parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"/>` and then in your test case use `@Parameters({ "browserName" })`. You can also do this in `@beforeClass`. But consider redesigning what ever you are doing that will solve a lot of issues